# What determines how program arguments needs to be separated?

Tags: shell, arguments

I noticed that `kill` utility is able to accept arguments separated both by a space character and a newline:

```
$ sleep 120 & sleep 240 &
[1] 75341
[2] 75342
$ /bin/kill $(echo "75341 75342")
[1]-  Terminated: 15          sleep 120
[2]+  Terminated: 15          sleep 240
$ sleep 120 & sleep 240 &
[1] 75577
[2] 75578
$ /bin/kill $(echo -e "75577\n75578")
[1]-  Terminated: 15          sleep 120
[2]+  Terminated: 15          sleep 240
$
```

Am I correct that this is solely up to utility itself if it accepts arguments for example separated by a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to a utility are passed as a **list of strings**, not as a single string. Therefore the utility doesn't have any notion of separator between arguments. The arguments are just separate elements in the list, there's nothing “between” them.

The entity that splits a string into a list of arguments is the shell. The shell executes the command line like `/bin/kill $(echo "75341 75342")` by performing a [series of expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions). Specifically:

1. The command is broken down into tokens. I won't go into these rules in details; a token is basically either a punctuation sign or a sequence of characters not containing top-level whitespace. Here, the tokens are the string `/bin/kill` and the command substitution `$(echo "75341 75342")`, which itself is built from the `$(…)` operator and the tokens `echo` and `75341 75342`.
2. The command in the command substitution operator is executed. It is a simple command, with the command name `echo` and the single argument `75341 75342`. (The quotes are part of the shell syntax, they delimit a string, which becomes an argument to the command.)
3. The output of the command is `75341 75342␤` where `␤` is a newline character. The shell takes this output and strips off final newlines, yielding the string `75341 75342`.
4. Because the command substitution operator is used in a list context (outside of double quotes), it undergoes [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion). Word splitting consists of taking the string and splitting it into a list of strings based on the value of the `IFS` variable. By default, `IFS` contains the characters space, tab and newline, so the string is split at any sequence of these characters: it becomes the list of two strings `75341` and `75342`. Filename expansion doesn't change anything here.
5. We now have a list of three strings: `/bin/kill`, `75341` and `75342`. This is executed as the command `/bin/kill` with two arguments `75341` and `75342`.

With the command `/bin/kill $(echo -e "75577\n75578")`, the expansions are pretty much the same. Step 3 produces the output `75341␤75342␤`. At step 4, word splitting produces the same list `75341`, `75342` as before, because a newline and a space are equally valid word separators. Thus step 5 executes the exact same command.

As you can see, the step that determines what separates arguments is the word splitting step performed by the shell. You can experiment with this step by changing the value of `IFS`. For example, this produces again the same command:

```
IFS=+
/bin/kill $(echo "75341+75342")
```

Answer (score 2):

As you do not quote `$(echo -e "75577\n75578")`, it is up to the shell to handle it.

The way the shell parse what it get depends on a variable named IFS (Internal Field Separator). By default, it contains space, tab and new-line so that means any combination of these three characters is considered a valid separator between arguments.

Should you set it to a string that does not contain new-line, your command would receive the `\n` embedded with its argument and then will fail:

```
$ touch a b
$ echo "$IFS" | od -c
0000000      \t  \n  \n
0000004$ 
$ ls -l a b
-rw-r--r-- 1 jlliagre jlliagre 0 Nov 12 15:04 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 jlliagre jlliagre 0 Nov 12 15:04 b
$ ls -l $(printf "a\nb")
-rw-r--r-- 1 jlliagre jlliagre 0 Nov 12 15:05 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 jlliagre jlliagre 0 Nov 12 15:05 b
$ IFS=" "
$ ls -l $(printf "a\nb")
ls: cannot access a
b: No such file or directory
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is rather the `$( )` construct that replace new line by space. Just use `echo $(echo -e "75577\n75578")`.

Now try

```
cat <<EOF | kill
1234
5678
EOF
```

(with proper value).

Comment: The unquoted `$(...)` is subject to word splitting according to _IFS_, that's why it works. Compare something like `ls $(echo -e "-l\n-h")` with `(IFS=' '; ls $(echo -e "-l\n-h"))` .

Answer (score 0):

No, something is replacing newline.

```
% sleep 120 & sleep 120 &
15362
15363

% strace -f -eexecve /bin/kill $(echo "15362 15363")
execve("/bin/kill", ["/bin/kill", "15362", "15363"], [/* 18 vars */]) = 0

% strace -f -eexecve /bin/kill $(echo -e "15362\n15363")
execve("/bin/kill", ["/bin/kill", "15362", "15363"], [/* 18 vars */]) = 0
kill: can't kill pid 15362: No such process
...
```

Use strace(1) to determine how command line is passed then to your created processes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly about `kill`, even with (i.e) `ls` you'll have this behavior:

```
> touch file1 file2
> ls $(echo -e "file1 file2")
file1 file2
> ls $(echo -e "file1\nfile2")
file1 file2
```

This because it is not about the command itself, but about how bash deal with scripting. It will be more clear what I mean if you look at this from the 'scripting' side. Try redirecting the command inside a file, chmod it to 777 and execute:

```
> touch file1 file2
> ls $(echo -e "file1\nfile2")
file1 file2
> echo -e 'ls $(echo -e "file1\nfile2")' > tryme.sh
> cat tryme.sh
ls $(echo -e "file1
file2")
> chmod 777 tryme.sh
> ./tryme.sh
file1 file2
```